# How to mock the $refs attribute when doing unit testing with jest?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Below is a mounted I have in a vue component which I want to perform a unit testing on.

```
mounted () {
        const pageRef = this.$refs.tabRef.offsetParent.offsetParent;
        this.pageSize = {
            width: pageRef.offsetWidth,
            height: pageRef.offsetHeight
        };
},
```

and below is my unit test for the component

```
const propsData = {
    configs: {
        tabColor: "#f2f2f2ff",
        activeTabColor: "#4c4c4cff",
        background: "#ffffffff",
        tabData: [
            { id: "", name: "tab1", title: "New Tab", widgets: [], disabled: false },
            { id: "", name: "tab2", title: "Tab 2", widgets: [], disabled: false }
        ],
        eventConfig: []

    },
    id: "",
    mode: "preview",
    pageType: "pixels",
    pageSize: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
    zoomFactor: 1
};
describe("XSafeTabWidget", () => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    useQuasarComponent(localVue);

    let vm: any = null;
    let wrapper: any = null;
    let store: any = null;
    let newPropsData = clonedeep(propsData) as any;

    localVue.use(Vuex as any);

    wrapper = mount(XSafeTabWidget, {
      localVue,
      propsData,
      mocks: {
          $store: {
            getters: jest.fn(),
            dispatch: jest.fn()
          },
      }
    });

    store = new Vuex.Store({
        getters: {
            isWidgetSelected: (_store: any) => (_wgtId: string) => {
                return true;
            }
        },
        actions: {
          requestAction: (_store: any, action: any) => {
              switch (action.name) {
                  case "updateControlWidgetValue": {
                      newPropsData.value = action.payload;
                      wrapper.setProps(clonedeep(newPropsData));
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    });

    wrapper.setProps({ $store: store });

    vm = wrapper.vm as any;

    it("default data loaded correctly", () => {
        expect(vm.tabPosition).toBe("top");
        expect(vm.tabHeight).toBe(3);
        expect(vm.tabWidth).toBe(9.1);
        expect(vm.border).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

My issue now is that I am getting an error saying that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetParent' of null" which I assume it is because I have to mock my $refs in the unit testing component. How can I do so? I have tried many ways and I am still unable to get it to work. Thank you in advance.

I tried to do as below and it does not work

```
wrapper = mount(XSafeTabWidget, {
      localVue,
      propsData,
      mocks: {
          $store: {
            getters: jest.fn(),
            dispatch: jest.fn()
          },
          $refs: {
            tabRef: {
              offsetParent: {
                offsetParent: {
                  offsetWidth: 10,
                  offsetHeight: 10
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: What is tabRef? You need to mock a component that this ref refers to, not just a ref.

Comment: @EstusFlask The tabRef is a Vue ref which in my code is as below: <template> <div class="fit" :style="cssVars" ref="tabRef"> // Other codes... </div> </template> I believe i have already mock the tabRef which is in $refs. Not sure what Im doing wrong...

Comment: I don't think you can mock $refs the way you did it because it's not random component property like $store. The question doesn't contain this code. Since it's div ref, the problem is in how jest fake dom works, it cannot handle offsetParent correctly, among many other things